# Null coalescing operator on decimal and decimal

Tags: c#, null, operator-keyword, coalescing

I'm facing the following error while applying a null coalescing operator.

```
private decimal _currentImpulseId;
// ... later on used in public property getter as follows

public decimal CurrentImpulseId
{
  get { return _currentImpulseId ?? 0M; }
  set { _currentImpulseId = value; }
}
```

Following error is returned:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and
>   'decimal'

Why doesn't this work? Does the null coalescing operator not work with decimals or am I missing something here? I know how I can work around this without using the operator, but this somewhat baffled me so I wonder if you know the correct answer on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because `decimal` is a value type, not a nullable value type (e.g. `decimal?`) or a reference type.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

> ...and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types

The default value of a variable of type `decimal` is zero, so I am not quite sure why you would want to use this operator in this scenario.

Also, the backing field variable (`_currentImpulseId`) is not required as of .NET 3.0, since the introduction of [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) means you can just write

```
public decimal CurrentImpulseId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because decimal is a value type see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you have to make it nullable.
Try

```
private decimal? _currentImpulseId;
// ... later on used in public property getter as follows

public decimal? CurrentImpulseId
{
  get { return _currentImpulseId ?? 0M; }
  set { _currentImpulseId = value; }
}
```